# Websockets with Spring WebFlux: properly mix authentication data with event treatment

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-websocket, reactive-streams

I develop an application where users connect via WebSocket and exchange messages. I use Spring WebFlux and Reactive WebSockets. Security component provide me with a `Mono` containing current `Principal`:

```
Mono<Principal> = session.getHandshakeInfo().getPrincipal()
```

I did not found any other solution than `zip` this mono with inbound message flux and outbound message flux. In my opinion this is quite cumbersome, repetitive and ugly.

```
public class ChatSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    private Flux<DownstreamMessage> outputEvents;

    public ChatSocketHandler(Sinks.Many<DownstreamMessage> downstreamPublisher) {
        this.outputEvents = downstreamPublisher.asFlux();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
        var input = session.receive()
                .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                .map(this::toEvent)
                .flatMap(event -> Mono.just(event).zipWith(session.getHandshakeInfo().getPrincipal()))
                .doOnNext(objects -> /* do something with objects.getT1() and objects.getT2()*/)
                .then();

        var output = session.send(
                outputEvents
                        .flatMap(event -> Mono.just(event).zipWith(session.getHandshakeInfo().getPrincipal()))
                        .filter(objects -> /* Filter events based on event objects.getT1() and Principal objects.getT2() */)
                        .map(Tuple2::getT1)
                        .map(this::toJSON)
                        .map(session::textMessage)
                )
                .then();

        return Mono.zip(input, output).then();
    }
```

In your opinion, are there any other elegant solutions ?